Modificar estilo de label cuando input esta completo
no encontré en una búsqueda esto que necesito-
Tengo un form con varios input, que al seleccionarlos, le modifico el label con CSS con :focus, pero al terminar de completarlos y seleccionar otro se modifica. Necesito que, si se han completado, se queden con el estilo de cuando estaban seleccionados.
Aca el codigo, solo html y css y resumido para que te entienda el comportamiento, como ven en el css se le pone :focus al input y también una clase "-filled" que es lo quisiera agregarle para que quede fijo


.input{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 3rem;
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.input__input {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #fff
    padding: 0.5rem 2.5rem 0px 1rem;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 44;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.label{
     position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 3rem
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.input__label{
    color: #2d2d2d;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
    text-align: left;
}

.input__input:focus + .input__label, .input__input.-filled + .input__label{
top: 0.8rem;
    font-size: 12px;
}
<form action="" class="contactForm" name="formulario" id="formularioMKSContacto" method="post">
  <div class="autocomplete-form__form__wrapper">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="Telefono"class="label input tel -type-tel">
        <input type="tel" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" required="" class="input__input">
        <p class="input__label">Ingresá tu número</p>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="Email"class="label input tel -type-tel">
        <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" required="" class="input__input">
        <p class="input__label">Ingresá Email</p>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form__buttons">
      <button type="submit" class="autocomplete-form__form__button button cta -color-red">
      <span tacc="autocompleteForm-button-text" class="button__inner cta__link">Enviar</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>



Buscando encontré este código de jquery, agrega la clase, pero los input están vacíos en un inicio por lo que se agrega inicialmente, y necesito que cuando se seleccione se agregue la clase y si se completa se quede, y si no se elimine. Y ahí ya no encontré nada


$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(".input__input").val().length < 1) {
    $(".input__label").addClass("-filled");
    return false;
  }
});



Es pero haya sigo claro, Gracias por la respuesta

Debes agregar el código que se comporta de esa manera para recibir la ayuda correctamente, sino vamos a divagar todo el dia sobre lo que te ocurre sin saber ni como está escrito.  Te recomiendo la lectura de [example] y ya que pareces nuevo tambien que hagas el [tour] y aprendas como se elaboran las preguntas para tener mejor aceptación y que te podamos ayudar leyendo [ask], gracias.

Si tu campo está marcado como required podrías usar css puro imagino: input:required:valid { /* estilos aquí */  }

@Benito-B, gracias pero no es exacto lo que necesito, ya modifique para que este mas claro

@masterguru Gracias por aclararlo y explicar, mala mía perdón. Ya modifique la pregunta espero este mejor!

Si, es suficiente, gracias, he votado para que la reabran y así podrán responderte (aunque aún faltan un par de votos más para ello).

Mientras tanto, te sugiero que aprendas sobre la función addEventListener, el evento focusout y busques información sobre la delegación de eventos en javascript, que todo eso junto podria ayudarte a encontrar una solución (aunque seguro que hay más soluciones quizás no tan rebuscadas)

El problema es que no puedes diferenciar si es la primera vez que se carga la página (el input está "limpio" y no se ha tocado) o si se ha borrado el contenido (el input está "sucio" o "tocado", hay muchos nombres para este estado :)). Te recomiendo usar un data attribute por ejemplo data-limpio="true" y en tu css aplica solo el estilo a quien no tenga ese data. Vas a necesitar un poquito de JS para en cuanto el usuario escriba cualquier cosa simplemente eliminas ese data y listo. Así aunque de primeras apliques la clase, no se aplicará el css porque tendrá el atributo limpio

Puedes hacerlo con JavaScript, pero también hay una opción de hacerlo sin necesidad de utilizar JS, sólo con CSS (con un pequeño cambio en HTML). En esta respuesta comento esta segunda opción.
Como te sugieren en los comentarios, las pseudo-clases :valid e :invalid son una buena idea, pero no quieres que los campos tengan esos estilos al cargar la página. Para ello, CSS cuenta con las pseudo-clases :user-valid y :user-invalid que funcionan igual que las otras, sólo que se aplican una vez el usuario haya interactuado con los campos. De ese modo, no tendrán los estilos que indicas cuando la página se carga por primera vez.
.input__input:focus + .input__label, 
.input__input:user-valid + .input__label,
.input__input:user-invalid + .input__label {
    top: 0.8rem;
    font-size: 12px;
}

Aquí puedes verlo funcionando:


.input{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 3rem;
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.input__input {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #fff
    padding: 0.5rem 2.5rem 0px 1rem;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 44;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.label{
     position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 3rem
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.input__label{
    color: #2d2d2d;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
    text-align: left;
}

.input__input:focus + .input__label, 
.input__input:user-valid + .input__label,
.input__input:user-invalid + .input__label {
    top: 0.8rem;
    font-size: 12px;
}
<form action="" class="contactForm" name="formulario" id="formularioMKSContacto" method="post">
  <div class="autocomplete-form__form__wrapper">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="Telefono"class="label input tel -type-tel">
        <input type="tel" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" required="" class="input__input">
        <p class="input__label">Ingresá tu número</p>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="Email"class="label input tel -type-tel">
        <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" required="" class="input__input">
        <p class="input__label">Ingresá Email</p>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form__buttons">
      <button type="submit" class="autocomplete-form__form__button button cta -color-red">
      <span tacc="autocompleteForm-button-text" class="button__inner cta__link">Enviar</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>



Esto funciona mejor, pero aún hay un problema: cuando el usuario introduce un email que no es válido, el campo se queda pequeño (correcto); pero si lo borra, el label se queda pequeño incluso cuando el campo está vacío (incorrecto).
Esto ocurre porque el campo vacío no es válido al tener required. Y aquí es donde viene la pequeña triquiñuela. Cuando un campo está vacío, se muestra el placeholder (si lo tiene) y CSS cuenta con una pseudo-clase para seleccionar campos que muestran el placeholder: :placeholder-shown.
Entonces, lo que quieres es seleccionar los campos que sean inválidos y no estén vacíos. Añade un placeholder a los inputs (con espacios en blanco o sin nada, pero debe estar en el código) y cambia un poco el selector para que no sólo seleccione los campos no válidos después de interacción de usuario, sino también los que no estén mostrando el placeholder (es decir, los que tiene algún valor):
.input__input:focus + .input__label, 
.input__input:user-valid + .input__label,
.input__input:user-invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) + .input__label {
    top: 0.8rem;
    font-size: 12px;
}

Una vez hecho ese par de cambios, tienes la funcionalidad que quieres sólo con HTML y CSS, sin necesidad de tener que verificar los campos con JS:


.input{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 3rem;
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.input__input {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #fff
    padding: 0.5rem 2.5rem 0px 1rem;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 44;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.label{
     position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 3rem
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.input__label{
    color: #2d2d2d;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
    text-align: left;
}

.input__input:focus + .input__label, 
.input__input:user-valid + .input__label,
.input__input:user-invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) + .input__label {
    top: 0.8rem;
    font-size: 12px;
}
<form action="" class="contactForm" name="formulario" id="formularioMKSContacto" method="post">
  <div class="autocomplete-form__form__wrapper">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="Telefono"class="label input tel -type-tel">
        <input type="tel" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" required="" class="input__input" placeholder="">
        <p class="input__label">Ingresá tu número</p>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="Email"class="label input tel -type-tel">
        <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" required="" class="input__input" placeholder="">
        <p class="input__label">Ingresá Email</p>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form__buttons">
      <button type="submit" class="autocomplete-form__form__button button cta -color-red">
      <span tacc="autocompleteForm-button-text" class="button__inner cta__link">Enviar</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>



